# Using WebProxy with HttpClient.SendAsync() and HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

I am able to use a proxy by implementing the class IWebProxy and doing this:
HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

```
aHandler.UseCookies = true;
aHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
IWebProxy proxy = new AWProxy(new Uri("http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx"));
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");
aHandler.Proxy = proxy;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(aHandler);
```

By calling client.GetAsync("http://google.com") I was able to get a successful response message back. However I want to be able to use HttpRequestMessage for control over headers and post/put content.

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri); 

//add other headers
requestMessage.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

But if I use HttpRequestMessage I get this exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Unable to connect to the remote server. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What's the callstack of the NullReferenceException?  Are you sure it isn't in the call to your proxy implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Add them directly to your HttpClient.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0;     Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```

Comment: Thanks, had not know that was possible. However, I also want to be able to generate different types of requests such as post, put, delete, options, trace, get, head. I believe http client only supports post, put, delete and get.

Comment: @Ryan  Use `SendAsync` with `new RequestMessage() {Method = new HttpMethod("TRACE") }`

Comment: What was actually the problem though? Why was the exception being raised?